# SQL Server - storing ulong as primary key

Tags: sql-server, database-design, primary-key, datatypes

I need to store `ulong` values as a primary key in SQL Server. Since SQL Server doesn't have a `ulong` datatype (or for that matter anything `unsigned`), the only way to go is to have column as `varbinary(8)`.

Now, having a `varbinary` as a PK doesn't sound like a good idea. So what are the alternatives to store `ulong` values?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64681/discussion-on-question-by-mrchief-sql-server-storing-ulong-as-primary-key).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming by `ulong` that you mean a 64-bit unsigned integer.

Your best option if you truly need to span the entire range of a `ulong` is to use `NUMERIC(20,0)` or larger.  If you need to enforce the range of values to those valid for your data type, use a check constraint to restrict the values to between 0 and 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.  Alternately, you could use `VARBINARY(8)`, but your application would have to be base-aware.